# 2011 27" Intel iMac 12,1 No boot from internal HD/usb external HD/usb installer

Tags: hard-drive, imac, startup

When it (finally?) failed today, the screen went gray with vertical lines. GPU... maybe? There was a now expired recall for the AMD Radeon GPU. I have read where people have failing power supplies for this vintage but wouldn't a failed PS just fail? It still powers on and I can get to the Options screen, run in verbose mode, and single-user DOS screen, so the PS supply isn't "dead". The Mac runs flawlessly from a live Linux Mint CD but I am told graphics are software generated and not reliant on the questionable AMD GPU.

It will not boot from internal HD, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, USB installer or external High Sierra HD, resulting in logo, progress bar, and then gray screen. Those 3 options were tested as working over the past 2 days when the mac was still somewhat alive and even confirmed working on another iMac. <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> progresses 50% then gray screen. Can't start in safe mode.

I used Target mode and the utilities show both the boot SSD and the 1TB storage drive are fine. Starting Mac with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> indicates the hardware is fine. Single user `/sbin/fdsk -fy` indicates the boot drive is OK.

Throwing parts and my wallet at this geezer is questionable as it can get pricey to troubleshoot this machine unless there is a method to specifically identify the fault that causes the crash/failed boot.

Is there such a program and can I get it to run from the good Mac in Target mode or if the bad boy comes back to life is there such a resource?
An Apple tech surmises that the disks aren't being mounted, without explaining why, but offered no remedy.